# Key pressing events in Dart

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have read the docs for the KeyEvent class ([link here](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.KeyEvent)), and also several SOF questions, but I still can't make Dart listen to my key press. I'm using Polymer-dart 0.16, and could do it with `core-a11-keys`, but it doesn't incorporate the PLUS and MINUS keys, which I need.

From a custom element `<myElement>` that I defined, I want to be able to listen to different keys being pressed (anywhere in the element). This element has of course its correspondings `html` and `dart` files. Should I listen the key being pressed from the `html` or the `dart`? The doc seems to specify that both the listening and the handling are done in the `dart` with this example:

```
// Initialize a stream for the KeyEvents:
var stream = KeyEvent.keyPressEvent.forTarget(document.body);
// Start listening to the stream of KeyEvents.
stream.listen((keyEvent) =>
    window.console.log('KeyPress event detected ${keyEvent.charCode}'));

...
// Add a new KeyEvent of someone pressing the 'A' key to the stream so
// listeners can know a KeyEvent happened.
stream.add(new KeyEvent('keypress', keyCode: 65, charCode: 97));
```

I guess that last line is *simulating* an user pressing a key. But if I don't add it, no key press is listened.

In short terms:
**Could someone please give a simple example of how to listen and handling the key press event?**

**EDIT**
A simple way of imagine what I'm trying to do, is to think about Google Inbox. Let's say you have several mails on your inbox, and you want to move between them. In this app you can do it with LEFT and RIGHT arrows (along with many other shortcuts for different actions).

I'm trying to do something similar with Dart. Let's say that I have a custom element `<my-element>` where all the mails are shown. I want this element to be able to listen to some events, like UP and DOWN keys being pressed. Using [core-a11-keys](https://github.com/Polymer/core-a11y-keys), I was able to do it, putting

```
<core-a11y-keys target="{{ body }}" keys="up" 
on-keys-pressed="{{ selectPreviousItem }}"></core-a11y-keys>
```

inside the `myElement.html` (inside the tag `<polymer-element name='my-element'>`), where `selectPreviousItem` is my handler for the event, which is a method in `myElement.dart`. The thing is that core-a11-keys doesn't have all the possible keys on a keyboard (which I need). Therefore, I'm trying to do exactly the same thing but without core-a11-keys, this is: listening and handling the event of the user clicking UP (or others keys) when the focus is somewhere in `<myElement>` (the focus for example could be in `<myNestedElement>` inside `<myElement>`).

Comment: It doesn't matter if you do it in JavaScript or HTML. The example seems not to be from Polymer. Without Polymer you can't do it declaratively in HTML.

Comment: If you do it declaratively in a Polymer elemen the element needs to have the focus. With your above code focus isn't necessary because it listens on the entire page, with `this. onKeyPress.listen(...)` inside a Polymer element this element also needs to have the focus to be able to receive keyboard events.

Comment: There are several examples here on SO. Can you please add more details about your requirements. What element is supposed to have the focus when a key event should be captured,...

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added an edit with further explanatios. And ok for no Polymer equals no in HTML. I have two issues: the first is that I don't really understand that example code I put in the question (it is from the docs). And second, I wasn't able to making it actually listen to the keys being pressed (when I copied-pasted-arranged it).

Comment: The example code is some generic way to listen to events. It's similar to `document.body.onKeyPress.listen(...)`. AFAIK by default only input elements can have focus, therefore it might work better to listen on the body element like shown above. The declarative polymer syntax always binds to the Polymer elements it is applied to. You also have to ensure you are listening to the right event. There are keyDown, keyPress, keyUp. Not all keys produce each event. Sorry, I'm still not on my PC, which makes it cumbersome to look up more concrete information and I don't know it all by heart.

Comment: I'll try to play this weekend with the same code as the one in the example. Thanks for all your answers anyway, they helped me understand better. And thanks for always answering about Dart in almost every SO question :).